Business vs. Family Obligations
Under Jewish law, what are one's financial obligations to a business versus obligations to family? Can one take on extensive debts and other financial obligations with respect to a business that would put the financial security of one's family at risk if these obligations were not repaid? Or should one try to structure business financial obligations in a way that minimizes risks to one's family's financial wellbeing?

Welcome to MiYodeya, Abraham and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see below for a link to a guide intended to help new (and old) users to understand the site. Great to have you learning with us! https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites/3887#3887

This feels like an impossible thing to answer precisely. You have to take some risks in life and you have to try to make money and you have to try to support your family. I don't know what magic formula you're expecting to find about how to do all those effectively.

As best I can tell, there is no Law against taking out a loan - only against giving a loan with the purpose of profiting off of it such as via interest. Thus people may do what they need to do to get by and survive - the sin lies with those extorting those in need. This is also why the Law calls for the forgiveness of debts every seven years (not like the US' corrupt system of bankruptcy where the debts of commoners - like student loans - are nearly impossible to get forgiven). The rich / businesses get to isolate their debts from their personal finances.

We know Jews are permitted to take big risky loans from the story of Nakdimon ben Gurion who borrowed a huge sum of water from the Romans.
You have to give an accurate income statement to the creditor before taking the loan. If you deceive him, you have committed Geneivas Daas.
Even if someone defaults on an immense amount of money, the sum can only be collected from what he owns (or his estate if he dies) and his sale as a slave for up to 7 years. His children are protected from creditors. So they are relatively safe from his default and won't be sold into slavery themselves.
A person is obligated to support his children to various endpoints and is obligated to support parents who cannot take care of themselves. The Gemara in Kiddushin requires the father to teach his son a trade, swimming, and arrange a wife for him. If one's debt causes him to be unable to afford these things, he will miss out on these positive mitzvot and anything else he cannot afford.
You might be able to argue that just as one is obligated to guard one's health in order to serve God, one should also guard his wealth. So one shouldn't take on so much debt that repayment won't affect his ability to serve God well enough.
The Shema says to serve God with your Heart, Spirit, and Means (בְּכָל־לְבָבְךָ וּבְכָל־נַפְשְׁךָ וּבְכָל־מְאֹדֶךָ׃) . Just like one needs his body and soul, he also needs his property.
Summary:
It won't be a sin to take a big loan, obtained honestly, but you risk being unable to fulfill positive mitzvot.

Thank you so much for the excellent explanation!  It really helps clarify my thinking regarding some financial obligations that I am considering. Thank you again and wishing you well!

"obligated to support parents who cannot take care of themselves" Source?

link added......

Nakdiman hired Choni? Or he prayed himself?

You know what, I think I'm combining two similar stories
